Drake Equation with Random Walks
Goal
I'd like to use the Drake Equation with random walk theory to estimate the probability of aliens reaching Earth.

Drake Equation
The Drake Equation estimates the number of advanced civilizations in our galaxy:
$$
N_D = R^* \times f_p \times n_e \times f_l \times f_i \times f_c \times L
$$
Random Walk Probability Density Function
For a 3D random walk, the probability density function (PDF) for the distance $ r $ from the origin after $ n $ steps is:
$$
P(r,n) \approx \frac{1}{(2\pi n)^{3/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2n}\right)
$$
To find the probability $ P_\epsilon $ of reaching within a distance $ \epsilon $ of Earth, we integrate the PDF over the volume of a sphere with radius $ \epsilon $:
$$
P_\epsilon = \int_0^\epsilon P(r,n) \cdot 4\pi r^2 \, dr
$$
Substituting the PDF:
$$
P_\epsilon = \int_0^\epsilon \frac{1}{(2\pi n)^{3/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2n}\right) \cdot 4\pi r^2 \, dr
$$
Using WolframAlpha, it evaluates to:
$$
P_\epsilon = \frac{\sqrt{2/\pi} \left( \sqrt{\pi/2} n^{3/2} \text{erf} \left( \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2n}} \right) - \epsilon n \exp \left( -\frac{\epsilon^2}{2n} \right) \right)}{n^{3/2}}
$$
Probability of Reaching Earth with Bias
In the case of a biased random walk, the number of steps $ n $ is adjusted by the bias factor $ b $:
$$
n_{\text{biased}} = \frac{n}{b^2}
$$
Incorporating the bias factor $ b $ into the probability calculation:
$$
P_{\epsilon, \text{biased}} = \frac{\sqrt{2/\pi} \left( \sqrt{\pi/2} \left( \frac{n}{b^2} \right)^{3/2} \text{erf} \left( \frac{\epsilon b}{\sqrt{2n}} \right) - \frac{n \epsilon e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2 b^2}{2n}}}{b^2} \right)}{\left( \frac{n}{b^2} \right)^{3/2}}
$$
Combined Probability for Multiple Civilizations
The combined probability of at least one of $ N_D $ civilizations reaching within a distance $ \epsilon $ of Earth is given by:
$$
P_{\text{reach, biased}} = 1 - \left(1 - P_{\epsilon, \text{biased}} \right)^{N_D}
$$
Thus we have
$$
P_{\text{reach, biased}} = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2/\pi} \left( \sqrt{\pi/2} \left( \frac{n}{b^2} \right)^{3/2} \text{erf} \left( \frac{\epsilon b}{\sqrt{2n}} \right) - \frac{n \epsilon e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2 b^2}{2n}}}{b^2} \right)}{\left( \frac{n}{b^2} \right)^{3/2}} \right)^{N_D}
$$
Example Calculation
Let's calculate the probability using the following values:
\begin{align*}
N_D &= 100 \text{ (number of advanced civilizations)} \\
n &= 10^6 \text{ (steps)} \\
b &= 2 \text{ (bias factor)} \\
\epsilon &= 50 \text{ (light-years, transmitting TV/Radio signals into space )}
\end{align*}
Substituting these values into the final equation:
$$
P_{\text{reach, biased}} = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{2/\pi} \left( \sqrt{\pi/2} \left( \frac{10^6}{2^2} \right)^{3/2} \text{erf} \left( \frac{50 \times 2}{\sqrt{2 \times 10^6}} \right) - \frac{10^6 \times 50 e^{-\frac{50^2 \times 2^2}{2 \times 10^6}}}{2^2} \right)}{\left( \frac{10^6}{2^2} \right)^{3/2}} \right)^{100}
$$
Using WolframAlpha, the above calculation results in approximately:
$$
P_{\text{reach, biased}} \approx 0.026
$$
Thus, the probability that at least one of the 100 advanced civilizations has come within 50 light-years of Earth, is $\approx$ 2.6%.
Question
Does this approach provide a plausible partial explanation for the Fermi Paradox - "If life is so easy, someone from somewhere must have come calling by now"?

Your probability is the probability of reaching within $\epsilon$ of the starting point, not the Earth. Why is a random walk a good model? Civilisations don't explore in random directions.
